# Can't see files on Nautilus without sudo

Tags: bash, nautilus, sudo, ls

I can't see a tar I exported from Docker on Nautilus unless I `sudo xdg-open` the directory it's in, even though it's visible with non-`sudo` `ls` and the permissions appear to be in order:

ls -lha output:
[image]

This is what Nautilus shows: 
[image]

The file, however, IS visible through Nautilus if I use `sudo xdg-open .` (Image snipped for lack of reputation)

I run Docker using `sudo`, I guess that has something to do with it.

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files doesn't work either.

Comment: Try running `sudo chmod 0777 get-sentiment.tar` and then look in Nautilus again.

Comment: Thanks, didn't work. Still can't see it with xdg-open . but can see it with sudo xdg-open .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the system worked. Must've had something to do with refreshing log in credentials?